# Twisted chat server demo exits immediately

Tags: python, chat, twisted

Found the following chat server demo on Twisted's website:

```
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = SimpleLogger
factory.clients = []

application = service.Application("charServer")
internet.TCPServer(9999, factory).setServiceParent(application)
```

It didn't work in my project. It does not wait until the client connects to the server, but runs through the code and exits immediately. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have added filed a documentation ticket about this issue: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/8884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines above set up the connections to listen, but then immediately exit. You need to add something along the lines of:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.run()
```